# Can I use advanced filtering or any faster way to do this?

Tags: excel, vba

If you look at my code I am just stuck on how to use advanced filtering. for column A if it equals the date entered and column E equals ACH or > 0 then I want to copy column B into column D on another sheet, column D into column F, and column E into column C on another sheet. How can this be rewritten

[image]

I currently have this code that goes through the whole sheet based on Date entered in `TextBox1.value` and a few other criteria.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    Dim RawData As String, RawDataWorkingFolder As String, myrange As Range, cell As Range
    Dim targetSheetName As String
    Dim targetSheetFound As Boolean
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set aw = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim RawDataWorkingFolder2 As String, RawData2 As String
    
    Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("INFO")
    Unload Me
    BD = TextBox1.Value
    
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    RawDataWorkingFolder = Trim(aw.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value)
    RawData = Trim(aw.Worksheets(1).Range("E1").Value)
    Call Utilities.OpenWorkbook(RawDataWorkingFolder & RawData)
    
    For i = 2 To a
        If myrange.Cells(i, 1).Value = DateValue(BD) Then        'And myrange.Cells(i, 1).value <= DateValue(ED) Then
            If myrange.Cells(i, 5).Value = "ACH" Or myrange.Cells(i, 5).Value > 0 And myrange.Cells(i, 5).Value < 1000000 Then
                des = myrange.Cells(i, 2)
                Value = myrange.Cells(i, 4)
                ACH = myrange.Cells(i, 5)
                Worksheets("DAILY").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = des
                Worksheets("DAILY").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Value
                Worksheets("DAILY").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ACH
            
            ElseIf myrange.Cells(i, 5).Value = "CREDIT" Then
                des = myrange.Cells(i, 2)
                Value = myrange.Cells(i, 3) * -1
                ACH = myrange.Cells(i, 5)            
                Worksheets("DAILY").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = des
                Worksheets("DAILY").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Value
                Worksheets("DAILY").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ACH
            
            End If
        End If
    
        Application.StatusBar = "Data Is Running... Percentage complete Is " & Round((i / a * 100), 0) & "%"
    Next

Call Utilities.CloseWorkbook(RawData)
```

I was wondering if I can use Advanced filter method or if their is a faster way of getting this done. If so please any example or help would be great. Right now I click update daily and a textbox comes up that I enter the date required to copy the data. Everything works it is just slow. I would like to copy column B, C, D and E into another sheet. My criteria needs to be if its ACH, CREDIT, or any number above 0 and the date to be the same as date entered, then to copy the info.  Thank you.

Comment: Working in memory, rather than accessing the worksheet, would speed things up by an order of magnitude.  You could probably use the Advanced Filter to advantage. You don't provide enough information to create an example I could work from to give you any more ideas.

Comment: I updated the original with an image if possibly that helps

Comment: Helps a little.  If your criteria is a "date and some other criteria", it would seem that you could easily use an Advanced Filter. The Advanced Filter will let you use either `And` or `Or` for your criteria, and you can even use Formulas. Try it, and if you run into problems, post back.

Comment: If you look at my code I am just stuck on how to use advanced filtering. for column A if it equals the date entered and column E equals ACH or > 0 then I want to copy column B into column D on another sheet, column D into column F, and column E into column C on another sheet. How can this be rewritten.

Comment: If myrange.Cells(i, 1).Value = DateValue(BD) Then 
            If myrange.Cells(i, 5).Value = "ACH" Or myrange.Cells(i, 5).Value > 0 And myrange.Cells(i, 5).Value < 1000000 Then
                des = myrange.Cells(i, 2)
                Value = myrange.Cells(i, 4)
                ACH = myrange.Cells(i, 5)
                Worksheets("DAILY").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = des
                Worksheets("DAILY").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Value
                Worksheets("DAILY").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ACH

Comment: @MohamadBallout Please don't post code in comments, edit the original post and add it there.

Comment: @norie it is the same code that is in the original post I was just pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method of using the Advanced Filter to accomplish what you require.
You will have to adapt my code to your specifics.

I entered the date for filtering in an input box, but you can do that differently (and should also be validating that an actual date has been entered).

I use some "out of the way" area on the worksheet for the criteria range.

Hopefully the code is commented enough that you can understand it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyFiltered()
'declare all variables
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rCriteria As Range
    Dim myDate As Date
    
'get date to be filtered
myDate = InputBox("Enter date of interest:")

'set worksheets and ranges
Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")

With ws1
    Set rData = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=5)
    Set rCriteria = Range("AA1:AB3") 'could be anyplace on the worksheet
End With

'populate the criteria range
With rCriteria
    'Date Criteria: column A
    .Cells(1, 1) = rData(1, 1)
    .Cells(2, 1) = myDate
    .Cells(3, 1) = myDate
    
    'Column E criteria
    .Cells(1, 2) = rData(1, 5)
    .Cells(2, 2) = "ACH"
    .Cells(3, 2) = ">0"
    
End With

'Apply the filter
rData.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, criteriarange:=rCriteria

'Copy the filtered data to the appropriate columns on the destination sheet
'might want to clear the destination sheet first
ws2.Cells.Clear
With rData
    .Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws2.Cells(1, 4)
    .Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws2.Cells(1, 6)
    .Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws2.Cells(1, 3)
End With

'Remove the filter
ws1.ShowAllData
     
End Sub
```

**Original Data**
[image]

**Results after Filter**
[image]

Comment: This worked great, but I was wondering can I copy them without headers? Thank you

Comment: I added .offset(1) to .columns and it worked. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: One more question how can I add the values as a negative number on the other sheet? In my first code I was multiplying by -1 however trying that at the end of .Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws2.Cells(1, 6) *-1 did not work. Any help? Thank you

Comment: @MohamadBallout Which values?  If it is the column I marked credit, I suggest a `copy some cell containing a -1`, then `paste-special / multiply` over that column.  Record a macro to get an idea of the coding.

Comment: I tried a few things but still cant manage to get it to be a negative number before putting it on the second worksheet

Comment: @MohamadBallout Wrong order. First put it on the second worksheet, then convert it.  By the way, is this filtering method faster?

Comment: It is much faster because I have sheets that have thousands of rows and looping through them was taking some time. My problem is after I put them on the second sheet how do I select only those that were just put instead of the whole column. Because Debit and Credit are shown under the same columns in that sheet and I just need the credit values to be negative.

Comment: @MohamadBallout You are adding more and more complexity to your problem. It seems that the issue you asked about, although readily solvable, did not convey the full picture of your issues.  One way would be write the range to some throw-away area; change the sign as I mentioned, then copy-paste it to where you really want it to be.  But if there is going to be any more complexity to your real problem, consider posing a new question where you can present what you have done already, and what your current problems are. Obviously not necessary if this is all that is left to be solved.